# how to read a pdf inside a website without downloading the file

Tags: python, database, pdf, web-scraping, tabula

I want to get the data from a pdf that its inside a website, i have tried with tabula but it gave me the following error:

```
CalledProcessError: Command '['java', '-Dfile.encoding=UTF8', '-jar', 'C:\\Users\\Hector\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\tabula\\tabula-1.0.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar', '--guess', '--format', 'JSON', 'C:\\Users\\Hector\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\3231632d-81cd-4914-b5e9-cc12f03b607e.pdf']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

[image]

```
from tabula import read_pdf

df = read_pdf("url")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o). For example:

```py
# import io, tabula
pdfUrl = 'https://www.premera.com/documents/052166_2023.pdf'
r = requests.get(pdfUrl, headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
r.raise_for_status()
tabula.read_pdf(io.BytesIO(r.content), pages='6')[0]
```

I'm not sure the page link will work as `pdfUrl` since it's embedded, so if `tabula.io` raises some error, try the download link of the pdf instead.